# TiltEffect on longListSelector Items, windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5, longlistselector

This may sound really NOOBI! 
I have a `LongListSelector` for showing some items in my app, and I wanted to add this cool effect called `TiltEffect` to the items so they show some interaction as user taps on one of the them. 
For that matter I searched the internet and came up with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941108%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) link on MSDN and I have done as instructed there. I downloaded the code sample, added the discussed class to my project and in the `MainPage.xaml` I added the following lines:

```
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    local:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
```

alnd also in the class `TiltEffect.cs` I added `LongListSelector` as a `TiltableItem` like this:

```
    static TiltEffect()
    {
        // The tiltable items list.
        TiltableItems = new List<Type>() { typeof(ButtonBase), typeof(ListBoxItem), typeof(LongListSelector),};
        UseLogarithmicEase = false;
    }
```

Now the problem is that when any of the items on the `LongListSelector` is tapped, the whole `LongListSelector` tilts instead of only the tapped item.
please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052734/tilteffect-and-longlistselector

Comment: @KooKiz, thanks, you're right, I had seen that page but didn't go through the answer completely... :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052734/tilteffect-and-longlistselector)
I wrapped my `DataTempalte` in a `ListBoxItem`, now it looks like this:

```
    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MyLongListSelector"
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding My_Items}"
                                    SelectionChanged="MyLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">

                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBoxItem >
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,7" local:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" MinWidth="460">

                                <StackPanel.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/Photos/items.png"/>
                                </StackPanel.Background>                                

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center"
                                           Margin="0, 5, 0, 15" FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/BNazanin.ttf#B Nazanin"/>                                                                    
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    </DataTemplate>                        

                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try adding type that you used as a jumplist item to The tiltable items Collection instead of LongListSelector.